# Intermittent Port Open/Close

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port

I'm experiencing intermittent port opening issues. I have a server which uses TCP running on port `8080` in CentOS 6. `iptables` is disabled and port `8080` shows it is `LISTENING` for traffic.

Here is a simple diagram on how the network is setup: Internet ↔  modem/router (ARRIS TG862S) ↔ router (LINKSYS WRT1900AC) ↔ server.

I can access the server from any device hanging off the 2 routers behind my modem. I can also `ping` and do successful traceroutes from another device located in a different country. `traceroute` ends at my modem's IP (ICMP disabled on my routers).

ARRIS modem/router is routed with NAT. WAN IP is DHCP (but hasn't changed over the course of a week and this project). DMZ is enabled with the WAN IP of the IP given to me by my ISP and Private IP of my LYNCSYS router (`192.168.0.102`). Firewall is disabled. Statically assigned IP address for the LYNCSYS router (`192.168.0.102`).

LYNCSYS is connected to the ARRIS modem via Ethernet. NAT is enabled. Firewall is disabled. Port Forwarding is enabled - External/Internal port `8080`, both TCP and UDP. Static IP address assigned to my TCP server (`192.168.1.150`).

TCP Server running on CentOS6, port `8080`. Connected to LYNCSYS router via Ethernet cable. `iptables` disabled. Has Internet connectivity.

I'm using `canyouseeme.org` in order to verify that the port is open. Normally, `canyouseeme.org` cannot detect port `8080` open. BUT, if I delete the port forwarding out of the modem/router, re-add it, and then immediately check `canyouseeme.org`, port `8080` is shown as open. But, after about 10 seconds, `canyouseeme.org` reports the port is closed. I have screenshots to prove it. At one point I could access the server for about 60 seconds, then it went down.

Thinking that there may be an issue with `canyouseeme.org`, I also tested for open ports with `http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/`. Same thing, port `8080` closed unless I delete the port-forwarding in the router and then port `8080` only stays up for less than 10 seconds.

It sounds like port security to me, but then again... why would it create a flapping effect? Why when I delete the port forwarding out of my router, and re-add, the port stays open for a few seconds?

Answer (score 0):

I put the router/modem in "bridged mode" instead of "routed with NAT".  Fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you expand upon how you achieved that? It would help others with a similar issue in the future.